# How to automate Dislocker process?

Tags: 14.04, scripts

I have a bitlocker encrypted external hard disk which I use frequently on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. 
Everytime I connect my hard disk I have to enter the following four commands:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb1 -u -- /media/bitlocker
#Prompts to Enter unlock password
sudo -i
#Prompts to Enter root password
cd /media/bitlocker/
mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

How do I automate the above process using a shell script or python script?
I want the password to be given automatically on prompt and automate the entire process without any password prompts.

I wrote the following script:

```
  echo 'unlock' | sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb1 -u -- /media/bitlocker
  echo 'rootpass' | sudo -i
  cd /media/bitlocker/
  mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Following errors I received:

```
 Enter the user password: Sun Jan 31 22:00:30 2016 [CRITICAL] None of     the provided decryption mean is decrypting the keys. Abort.
 *** Error in `dislocker': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000055b27d7f86a0 ***
 stdin: is not a tty
 -bash: line 1: rootpass: command not found
 mount: only root can do that
```

Comment: put "echo (root password) | sudo -S mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount/" instead of "mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount" and try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (unlock password) | sudo -S dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb1 -u -- /media/bitlocker
echo (root password) | sudo -S -i
cd /media/bitlocker/
mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Save this as script.sh in gedit. Use chmod +x script.sh in the directory you created the file. Run the script --> ./script.sh

Edit: added -S after sudo

Comment: I tried the above code and received few errors. I've updated my post.

Comment: Can you try adding -S after sudo in both cases, that's my bad sorry.

Comment: -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
                the standard input instead of the terminal device.

Comment: Still getting error